# twilio connection error reason through preflight

Tags: twilio

I have created twilio preflight feature and tested by blocking twilio IP address.I was expected that I can get a reason of failure from twilio but preflightTest.on('failed') just return {} and do not get any info.

Quote of the document
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2160-august-11-2021

> preflightTest emits a failed event to indicate test failures.
> You can use the PreflightProgress events to better understand
> where the test failed and refer to this guide for interpreting common errors.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/build-js-video-application-recommendations-and-best-practices#connection-errors

These errors are listed on the guide, and if I expect these errors from preflightTest.on('failed'), but I have no way to check it.
Can you tell me whether I can get these errors when the error really happen?

```
SignalingConnectionError
SignalingServerBusyError
RoomMaxParticipantsExceededError
RoomNotFoundError
MediaConnectionError
```

my code

```
this.preflightTest = runPreflight(token);
    this.preflightTest.on('progress', (progress: string) => {
      callback(PREFLIGHT_EVENT.PROGRESS, { progress });
    });
    this.preflightTest.on('failed', (error: Error) => {
      callback(PREFLIGHT_EVENT.FAILED, { error });
    });
    this.preflightTest.on('completed', (report: PreflightTestReport) => 
    {
      callback(PREFLIGHT_EVENT.COMPLETED, { report });

    });
```

I can show error reason only for TurnServersReachable and SignalingGatewayReachable  as of now

```
if (progress === 'dtlsConnected' ||progress === 'peerConnectionConnected') {
 setTurnServersReachable(true);
}

if (progress === 'mediaAcquired') {
  setSignalingGatewayReachable(true);
}
```

I expect I can get SignalingServerBusyError or other errors in some way

---

---

logs when connection failed

```
preflightUpdate STARTED {}
progress: mediaAcquired
progress: connected
progress: mediaSubscribed
preflight error: Error: Timed out waiting for : wait for tracks to start
FAILED {"error":{}}
```

logs when connection succeed

```
STARTED - {}
 progress: mediaAcquired
 progress: connected
 progress: mediaSubscribed
 progress: iceConnected
 progress: dtlsConnected
 setTurnServersReachable true
 setProgress dtlsConnected
 progress: peerConnectionConnected
 progress: mediaStarted

 COMPLETED  {"report":{"testTiming":{"start":1635505791878,"end":1635505807198,"duration":15320},"networkTiming":{"dtls":{"start":1635505796743,"end":1635505796963,"duration":220},"ice":{"start":1635505796449,"end":1635505796743,"duration":294},"peerConnection":{"start":1635505796451,"end":1635505796993,"duration":542},"connect":{"start":1635505791908,"end":1635505795479,"duration":3571},"media":{"start":1635505795503,"end":1635505797168,"duration":1665}},"stats":{"jitter":{"min":0.01,"max":0.021,"average":0.013999999999999999},"rtt":{"min":180,"max":544,"average":296.5},"packetLoss":{"min":0,"max":0,"average":0}},"selectedIceCandidatePairStats":{"localCandidate":{"transportId":"RTCTransport_0_1","candidateType":"srflx","port":53186,"address":"49.106.217.239","priority":1685987071,"protocol":"udp"},"remoteCandidate":{"transportId":"RTCTransport_0_1","candidateType":"relay","port":59164,"address":"54.65.63.217","priority":41820159,"protocol":"udp"}},"iceCandidateStats":[{"transportId":"RTCTransport_0_1","candidateType":"host","port":53185,"address":"172.30.112.1","priority":2122260223,"protocol":"udp"},{"transportId":"RTCTransport_0_1","candidateType":"relay","port":59164,"address":"54.65.63.217","priority":41820159,"protocol":"udp"},{"transportId":"RTCTransport_0_1","candidateType":"host","port":53186,"address":"192.168.43.2","priority":2122194687,"protocol":"udp"},{"transportId":"RTCTransport_0_1","candidateType":"srflx","port":53186,"address":"49.106.217.239","priority":1685987071,"protocol":"udp"},{"transportId":"RTCTransport_0_1","candidateType":"relay","port":36411,"address":"54.65.63.217","priority":8265471,"protocol":"udp"},{"transportId":"RTCTransport_0_1","candidateType":"relay","port":26527,"address":"54.65.63.217","priority":41820159,"protocol":"udp","relayProtocol":"udp"}]}}
Test completed in 15320  milliseconds.
It took 3571 milliseconds to connect
It took 1665 milliseconds to receive media
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to run the preflight test? Also, are you able to run the test and listen not only to the `failed` event, but also the `progress` and `debug` events and share the results of the logs? Finally, you can see [the code that runs the preflight test here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/blob/4986d9e7674f626f5ce0ffc91ad16f3343e3a4f1/lib/preflight/preflighttest.ts) it might help understand what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I added my code. and clarified what I wanted to do

Comment: Are you able to run the test and share the results of the logs?

Comment: i have added a log for successful case and failed case. failed one is logged by blocking twilio ip address

Comment: I think this is likely best dealt with in the Twilio Video JS repo. Can you [open an issue here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues) and the Video team will be able to take a look at it.

Comment: ok thank you vry much, I wil post on github